# Botão Comprar Agora

Tags: woocommerce

Na loja Woocommerce tenho o botão Adicionar carrinho, gostaria de colocar um ao lado Comprar agora que encaminha o usuário direto no checkout, utilizei o seguinte código:

```html
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'my_extra_button_on_product_page', 30 );

function my_extra_button_on_product_page() {
  global $product;
 echo '<button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">Compre agora</button>';
}
```

Algo parecido como esta imagem, um dos botões leva o usuário para o carrinho de compras e o outro direto para o checkout
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mas qual seu problema? Seja mais específico sobre como podemos lhe ajudar...

Comment: Na template da loja só tenho o botão Adicionar carrinho,eu gostaria de adicionar um outro botão ao lado que direcione o usuário direto para o checkout, tipo um Compre agora